# String substring(i,j) throw IndexOutOfBounds Exception in method() but not in main()

Tags: java, methods, substring, program-entry-point, stringindexoutofbounds

```
public class Longest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String tc = "babad";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(tc.substring(0,tc.length()));
        System.out.println(sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString())); 
        //no exception

        System.out.println(longestPalindrome(tc)); // throw exception
    }
    public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        if(s.length()<2)
            return s;
        int max = 0;
        int beg = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j = s.length();j>=0;j--)
            {
                if(isPalindrome(s,i,j) && j-i>max)
                {
                    max = Math.max(j-i, max);
                    beg = i;
                }
                if(max == s.length())
                    return s;
            }
        }
        return s.substring(beg, beg+max);
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String s,int left, int right)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s.substring(left, right));
        return sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

My question is why eclipse threw out an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when isPalindrome() was invoked but didn't throw that exception when it run the same code in main().

Comment: Your use of `StringBuffer` here is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why this may happen, because in isPalindrome(), the JVM first check the grammar, j cannot be smaller than i so I change 
    for(int j = s.length();j>=0;j--)
into
    for(int j = s.length();j>=i;j--)
That exception is now gone.